# C# fire event when database connection fails for 5 seconds

Tags: c#, sql, database, timeout

I've got a form that calls a database on a continuous loop with a background worker to update a datagridview (which is bound to a datatable).

I want to fire an event when the background worker hasn't been able to access the database for 5 seconds. The event will turn the form's background red (I have this working when the event is fired).

I'm using the following method:

```
public DataTable PollDatabase(string query) // return the results of the query
{
    var ret = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        _adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, _pollConnection);
        _adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 1;
        _adapter.Fill(ret);

        OnSuccessfulPoll();
    }
    catch (SqlException e) // only handle sql exceptions (break on all others)
    {
        OnUnsuccessfulPoll(e);
    }

    return ret;
}

private void OnSuccessfulPoll()
{
    if (FormIsRed) 
    {
        OnDbConnectionStatusChanged(this, null);
        FormIsRed = false;
    }

    OnSuccessfulPollEvent(this, null);

    _lastSuccessfulPoll = DateTime.Now;
}

private void OnUnsuccessfulPoll(Exception e = null) 
{
    TimeSpan timeSinceLastPoll = DateTime.Now - _lastSuccessfulPoll;

    if (!FormIsRed && timeSinceLastPoll.TotalSeconds > 5) // wait 5 second then turn red!
    {
        OnDbConnectionStatusChanged(this, null);
        FormIsRed= true;
    }
}
```

But it takes around 15-20 seconds for my event to fire!

I've checked the Command and Connection timeout for my Sql Polling, they're both set to 1 second.

Can anyone suggest what is wrong or a better way to do this?

Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE:**

I added a timer to go off after 5 seconds unless cancelled to solve this issue.

The background worker still attempts to poll the database with the same query to have it go through when the connection is re-established (if it just temporarily dropped out) or until the program is reset by the user (when they notice the form has been red for a long time).

I'm still having similar issues, it takes around 10-20 seconds for the program to realise that the connection has been re-established (it tried to run the query and it was successful).

Please let me know what could be wrong or if you have a better way to do this.

Comment: How long does one roundtrip take? If a single select on the database takes 15-20 seconds, this behaviour is to be expected.

Comment: You shouldn't perform visualization in database logic. It should be enough to have single event and then window/form will perform timer-based *blink*. If you can't control how long it takes for sql to execute, then maybe you can put it into a separate thread, provide timeout after running this thread and simply ignore results of query if it is completed too late.

Comment: @nvoigt roundtrip takes around 25-30ms